# performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, performselector

I was trying the below code but `[self performSelector:handler withObject:data afterDelay:0]` in the sync function does not call the `handler1` or `handler2` methods, even when I'm passing the handlers from `initWithType` method. The handler is not going null I have already checked that.

Can someone please tell me what is going wrong?

```
- (instancetype)initWithType:(NSInteger *)Handler 
    {
    switch(Handler)
    {
    case 0:
           [self sync:@selector(handler1:) withURL:SyncURL];
           break;
    case 1:
           [self sync:@selector(handler2:) withURL:SyncURL];
           break;
    default:
           break;
    }

-(void)sync : (SEL) handler withURL:(NSString *)str1{
  Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
  NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

  if(networkStatus==NotReachable)
  {
      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Connection can't be established "  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
      [alert show];
      [alert release];
      return;
  }
  else{
      NSData *poststring=[syncString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
      NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
      [data appendData:poststring];
      NSString * postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[data length]];
      NSMutableURLRequest * request =[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
      NSString *ad_user;
      NSString *ad_password;
      NSString *ad_params;
      ad_user = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"username"];
      ad_password = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"password"];
      NSString *password = [Utility URLEncodeStringFromString:ad_password];
      ad_params = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"ad_user=%@&ad_password=%@",ad_user,password];
      NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@?&%@",str1,ad_params];
      [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str]]];
      [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
      [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
      [request setTimeoutInterval:240];
      [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
      [request setHTTPBody:data];
      NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
      NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
      if(error!=NULL)
      {                                                
        NSLog(@"error=%@",error.localizedDescription);
      }
      else
      {
        [self performSelector:handler withObject:data afterDelay:0];
      }
   }];

    [task resume];
}

}

-(void)handler1:(id )data{
//lines of code to execute
}

-(void)handler2:(id )data{
//lines of code to execute
}
```

Comment: Why do you need exactly `performSelector`? Because you can do the same with GCD, by using dispatch_after.

Comment: Also, it's unclear why do you need delay 0?

Comment: Hi, I used performSelector because I would need to call two different functions based on the situation, by passing the function name to the selector it should decide which function to call. Any idea how to do this using dispatch_after?

Comment: delay 0 because i don't need any delay.

Comment: 1) Try to use https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418764-performselector.

2) If you want to re-implement with `dispatch_after` you should pass block, not selector. For example:

 typedef void (^Block)(id);
(void)sync:(Block) handler withURL:(NSString *)str1{
   ...
   handler(data);
}

 and call `sync` like:
case 0:
```[self sync:^(id data){  [self handler1:data];  } withURL:]```
case 1:
```[self sync:^(id data){  [self handler2:data];  } withURL:]```

Comment: @skyylex -performSelector:...afterDelay: is perfectly acceptable way to do this and there are reasons, though they are diminishing over time, to use that versus dispatch_after().

Comment: @VinealViji If you don't need a delay, then just call the method without a delay!

Comment: @bbum you're right initial idea with GCD was to avoid selectors and have delay. At the moment, `dispatch_after isn't required if there is no delay. Simple block is more than enough. Just as an alternative to performSelector. I just forgot to remove dispatch_after from the 2nd suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a fix.
i used `performSelector:withObject:` like @skyylex suggested. also i changed the type of handler from **SEL** to **NSString** and did this `[self performSelector:(NSSelectorFromString(handler)) withObject:data];`
it worked.

Comment: Do you know *why* that fixed it?  Because `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` and `-performSelector:withObject:` do the exact same thing save for the delay bit.  That the delayed version failed indicates that your code is running on a thread without a run loop and *that* implies that you are mucking with the UI from a thread, which is a serious bug.

Comment: It works with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` also but i used `performSelector:withObject:` as i don't need any delay. `NSSelectorFromString(handler)` actually solved my problem.

Comment: Your fix doesn't directly make sense.  I suspect you fixed a symptom and no the real problem.   I'd also suggest putting in an assert() to make sure that code is executing on the thread you expect.

Comment: Note that `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with delay 0 and `performSelector:withObject:` are very different. `performSelector:withObject:` calls the method synchronously (i.e.  waits for it to return, and the return value is returned from the `performSelector:withObject:`). `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with delay 0 schedules an *asynchronous* call to the method on the current run loop. This means it does not run before the `sync` method finishes. It only runs after the current task and all the previously scheduled tasks with no delay on the current run loop are done.